# What is the equivalent to WinAPI in Linux and macOS?

Tags: c++, api

I want to create a cross-platform GUI library and I have experience in WinAPI for the window but concerning the other platforms like Linux and macOS, I want to know what is the equivalent to WinAPI(Win32Api) in Linux and macOS?

Comment: Look up QT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)

Comment: @RichardCritten: I want to use the API of each platform.

Comment: There is nothing compared to Win32, even remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every operating system has its own API. [Linux API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_interfaces) for Linux and [Cocoa (API)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)) for Apple's operating systems. Also see [Portable Operating System Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) for POSIX compatible operating systems.

Comment: Can any developer use them directly like win32Api?

Comment: @LionKing yes. That's what they are meant for. They define their respective operating systems for developers.

Comment: Is the language of each of them C\C++?

Comment: @LionKing C for Linux API, and C subset of C++ for win32 api. I am not very familiar with MacOS but I think it uses Objectvie-C and Swift

Answer (score 0):

There is no *direct* equivalent. Win32 is a *windows specific* API. It has no equivalent in other operating systems. Well, it *does* have something equivalent, but the APIs are completely different.

You have to either use platform specific APIs on each system you support or use some cross-platform library (like `Qt` or similar) that will work across platforms and abstract away the platform differences for you.

Comment: Yes, platform-specific APIs that is what I intend.

Comment: Also, I heard that macOS has something called cocoa, I think that is the macOS APIs?.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there isn't any equivalent for WinAPI, but there are good alternatives.
I would recommend SDL 2. It has OpenGL and Vulkan support as well as it's own render functions. It supports Windows, MacOS, Linux, iOS, AppleTV and Android. You even can compile it on unofficially supported platforms. It also supports audio outputs. Also it has many add-ons that can be installed very easily.